# Meteor: wainOn (Iron Route) not working

Tags: meteor, javascript

I have this issue that the `rendered` function is called while the elements are not yet in the DOM. Let me describe my situation. The templates looks like this:

```
<template name="barfoo">
    <ol>
        {{#each bars}}
            <li item>{{title}}</li>
        {{/each}}
    </ol>
</template>
```

And the following javascript code

```
Template.barfoo.bars = function () {
    return Bars.find({});
};

Tempalate.barfoo.rendered = function () {
    var bars = Bars.find({}).fetch();
    var list = $('[items]');
};
```

When the `rendered` function is called `bars == list == []`.
So to fix this I implemented [Iron routes](https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router) like this

```
Bars = new Meteor.Collection('bars');

// Routes
Router.configure({
    layout: 'layout',
    loadingTemplate: 'loading',
    notFoundTemplate: 'notFound'    
});
Router.map(function () {
    this.route('/', {
        controller: 'BarsController',
    });
});

if (Meteor.isClient) {
    App = {
        subs: {
            bars: Meteor.subscribe('bars'),
            ...
        }
    };

    MainController = RouteController.extend({
        template: 'barfoo',
        before: function () { ... },
        waitOn: function () {
            return [App.subs.bars];
        }
    });
}

if (Meteor.isServer) {
    Meteor.startup(function () {
        Meteor.publish('bars', function () {
            return Bars.find({});
    });
}
```

All basics, but when I go now to localhost:3000 I still get in the `rendered` function empty lists . Any suggestions what do wrong here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume your are working with the latest version of `iron-router`. If that's the case you will also need to add `loading` hook to your router, so:

```
Router.onBeforeAction('loading');
```

Also note that `before` hook is marked as deprecated.

Comment: I need to dig into this, but you're right. I was not able to copy-past the `onBeforeAction` right away into my project (got a lookupHook error or something) but I did add the [action](https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router) method to my controller which did the trick! thnx!